# un-loading https

Tags: ssl, https

I'm using this code in functions.php to load https on my events-manager pages:

```
function my_em_force_ssl( $template ) {
    if ( ! is_ssl() && em_is_event_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( str_replace( 'http:', 'https:', get_permalink() ) );
        die();
    }

    return $template;
}

add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'my_em_force_ssl', 10 );
```

Is there a way to unload or revert back to http when leaving those pages?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but give it a shot:

```
function my_em_force_ssl() {
    if ( ! is_ssl() && em_is_event_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( str_replace( 'http:', 'https:', get_permalink() ) );
        exit;
    } elseif ( is_ssl() && ! em_is_event_page() && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' ) {
        wp_redirect(
            str_replace( 'https:', 'http:',
                add_query_arg(
                    $_GET, site_url( $GLOBALS['wp']->request )
                )
            )
        );
        exit;       
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_em_force_ssl', 10 );
```

And a heads up, `template_redirect` is an action, so no need to accept & pass back params :)

Comment: Thanks man, that worked like a charm :) Now I just need to figure out a way to load the images https and other site elements.. awesome!